# How to add a design template to an email?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have the below code in mailer:

```
#contact_mailer.rb 

def sendCode(message,email)
  all_body = "message: #{message} "
  mail(to: email, body: all_body,subject: 'Sample Email')
end
```

And in controller I call this function

```
ContactMailer.sendCode(rand_num, params[:email]).deliver
```

This sends the message, but without any design.
I have created a file `sendCode.html.erb` inside contact mailer with my design to the email.

How can I assign that email design to `sendCode()`?

Comment: Check out https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-layouts

Comment: Paste your **sendCode.html.erb** code here.

Comment: BTW, in Ruby, method names are given in [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), i.e. `send_code`. Your file should be renamed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the body argument, Rails will try to make use of `views/contact_mailer/sendCode.html.erb`

The `body` argument in `mail` method makes it send mail without making use of template. If you want to pass a variable to template, define it by the instance method f.e.

```rb
@message = "message: #{message} "
```

Use it in view by the same method call `@message`

```rb
<%= @message %>
```